# JPA: Grab One-to-Many relationship with multiple join tables inbetween

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I have 4 Tables: Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4.

- Table1 has a many to one relation to Table2
- Table2 has a many to one relation to Table3
- Table3 has a one to many relation to Table4

My intent is that Table1 will have a many-to-many member to Table4. That is, Table1 will have a List member of Table4's

```
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private UUID id;

   List<Table4> list; //This is the member of the question

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_2_id")
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private Table2 table2;

   
    ....
}

public class Table2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private UUID id;
   
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_3_id")
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private Table3 table3;
}

public class Table3 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private UUID id;
   
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_4_id")
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private Table4 table4;
}

public class Table4 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private UUID id;
   
    ....
}
```

I have attempted to use something like

```
@JoinTable(
        name = "Table3", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table_2_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table_4_id")
    )
```

... in an attempt for mapping Many to Many entities, but this approach doesn't seem like it will work since I have two intermediate tables.

How can I grab a list from a table that is a few tables away with a many to many relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a getter method that returns your list of Table4, like bellow? You already have all the mappings in place.

```java
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
...
  public List<Table4> getTable4List(){
     //navigate to the list of table4 through the other tables
     //return null (or empty list) if table2, table3 are null or empty
  }
```

You can put the getter in the entity to follow domain driven design but you can also put this in a service transactional method...

Comment: Yea..... yea I don't know why I didn't think about this. This is much easier since I can just call .get2().get3().... until I get the list.

I'll accept this since I ended up using something like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to read the values, you could try to use a "special" table name:

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "(select * from Table2 t2 join Table3 t3 on ...)", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table_2_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "table_4_id")
)
```

But here is the problem, you can't write to that because this is not a bidirectional mapping anymore. What you want to do here is usually done by traversing the graph in Java Code, or by using DTOs, for which I think [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) is the perfect match.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Table1.class)
public interface Table1Dto {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("table2.table3.table4")
    Set<Table4Dto> getTable4();

    @EntityView(Table4.class)
    interface Table4Dto {
        @IdMapping
        UUID getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`Table1Dto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, Table1Dto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<Table1Dto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!